# Creating Rows in Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am developing a java application. The idea is: Create a spreadsheet, open it, and let user enter data, then user has to press a button and a program reads the data entered by the user.

I have a method that creates this workbook

```
    private void createExcelSheet (Workbook wb, String path) throws Exception{
    try{

        wb = new XSSFWorkbook ();
        XSSFSheet ws = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("Initial Data");



        try{
        out = new FileOutputStream (path);
        wb.write(out);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "rundll32 url.dll, FileProtocolHandler " + path);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However, when user enters data, java cannot read it, because of NullException b/c row did not exist.

I went ahead an made a for look that creates sertain amount of rows, the downside is that user will have to enter the amount of rows  (which is sometimes unknown) but for now let leave it hardcoded:

```
    private void createExcelSheet (Workbook wb, String path) throws Exception{
    try{

        wb = new XSSFWorkbook ();
        XSSFSheet ws = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("Initial Data");


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            Row row = ws.createRow(i);


        }
        try{
        out = new FileOutputStream (path);
        wb.write(out);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "rundll32 url.dll, FileProtocolHandler " + path);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So now it works fine, I tried entering up to 5 rows and so worked fine. However then I tried entering more rows than I actually created, and expected some kind of OutOfBound exception, but everything was read and worked perfectly. So then I tried the following:

```
    private void createExcelSheet (Workbook wb, String path) throws Exception{
    try{

        wb = new XSSFWorkbook ();
        XSSFSheet ws = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("Initial Data");



            Row row = ws.createRow(0);



        try{
        out = new FileOutputStream (path);
        wb.write(out);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "rundll32 url.dll, FileProtocolHandler " + path);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

As you see here I created only first row, but somehow it creates all the rows in the workbook. Why does it work like this if I only create one row and specifically indicate index 0.

I do now need any code that solves that, I only want to understand the logic.

Comment: Hello Leah! Can you provide the project file?

Comment: Where is the code that was trying to read the spreadsheet and that was throwing a null-exception? Maybe that code could be changed so you would not to do any writing of rows.